# Using Cloudsearch/Solr for reporting

Tags: solr, report, bigdata, amazon-cloudsearch

Is is possible to use Cloudsearch/Solr engine to generate reports (using faceted search)? Is there a good way to generate custom reports on data (near realtime), even in a context that this data contains tags (in unlimited number), created by the end user?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible, for background info, I suggest you take a look at [Trey Grainger's presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkoyCxBXAiA) on that specific subject.